# help with jquery stop/dequeue

Tags: jquery

For my first real foray into jquery, I picked a doozie.  I wanted a "pull down, bouncing nav with a pull down search bar).  After tinkering for longer than I should admit, I arrived very happily at this: http://jsfiddle.net/2RqmU/38/

This does everything I want, just how I want it, with one exception: The search icon is queuing activity/hovers, and I can't figure out how to prevent it.  It's unclear to me why ".stop(true, false)." isn't working as it does on the animations of the other icons. I thought maybe this was a job for dequeue, but that's not helping either.

Any help greatly appreciated! Nearly there....

---

I'm not sure the appropriate etiquette here.  I just wanted to flag that this is only partially resolved.  The answer does effectively stop the queuing but a new hover/move-over forces the sliding to start anew (from the resting place), even if it hasn't returned to its resting place.  In other words, the sliding "resets" immediately on re-hover.  That makes it jerky on a quick re-hover, before the icon had a chance to return to its resting place.  The stop true/false on the other animations works fine in this respect.  But I can't get that same effect on the search icon, which operates by sliding (not animation as such).  Thanks.

Comment: I don't have anything to provide for your jQuery issue, but I just wanted to say that what you've done is pretty (*&^ slick.

Comment: Just remember to add a `min-width` to your `<body>` because it wraps around really ugly if the viewport is small.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the two appropriate cases of `.stop(true, true)` and change the search animation to this, it stops queuing for me:

```
$('#search-area').hover(function() {
    $('#search-reveal-container').stop(true, true).slideDown(200);
}, function() {
    if (!$('#query').is(':focus')) {
        $('#search-reveal-container').stop(true, true).slideUp({
            duration: 800,
            easing: 'easeOutBounce'
        });
    }
})
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/WGNa4/

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  That does stop the queuing, but is jumpy.  If you hover back on the the search icon before it has fully returned to its "resting state" it immediately jumps there.  I had that issue on the other icons before I switched from true/true to true/false for the stops.  Unfortunately, true/false doesn't work on that search animation here.